# STL + ARIMA (2,1,2) equation or algorithm

Tags: arima, algorithms

I have found all questions through this portal. I am very thankful to this community. This is my first post. This time, I did not find precisely the following question: how is the algorithm built of the model "STL + ARIMA (p,d,q)"?

I am working with daily data (2017.01-.01 till 2019.08.19, n=959) and I the best fit resulted of "SARIMA" and "STL + ARIMA". How would be the mathematical structure of STL+ ARIMA (2,1,2)?

Thanks!

Comment: STL decomposes the seasonal component from the time series first and then fits an ARIMA model on the remainder, SARIMA models the seasonal component directly.

Comment: Thanks, still would like to know the equation from "STL + ARIMA (2,1,2)"

Comment: See the documentation, STL uses loess smoothing to estimate the time series components.

Comment: See https://otexts.com/fpp2/forecasting-decomposition.html and https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima.html

Comment: Thanks Professor Hyndman, thats fantastic! I should have look more in details since I have your book